# append hours and minutes to get_selectedDate() from RadDatePicker control

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik, telerik-grid

How can I append hours and minutes  get_selectedDate?

```
var date = picker.get_selectedDate() //append here
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have a procedure that allows filtering between dates in a RadGrid, but If you select to filter between one day it isn't allowed. Therefore I need to append 23:59 to the EndDate value.

any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

C#:

For DateTime:

```
DateTime selectedDate = datePicker.get_SelectedDate();

DateTime formattedDate = new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, selectedDate.Day, 23,46,00);
```

Then set your date to your new date.

Written from my Droid X